# Let $X$ metric space connected by paths. If $U$ is open then every connected components of $U$ is open in $X$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

Let $X$ metric space connected by paths. If $U$ is open then every connected components of $U$ is open in $X$?

I tried a few things and I did not succeed, would like a tip.

Thank's

Comment: This claim is false; to make it true you also need local connectivity.

Answer (score 2):

A space $X$ (metric or not) has the property that "for every open set $U$ of $X$, all connected components of $U$ are open", iff $X$ is locally connected.

So the path-connectedness of $X$ is irrelevant here. Any path-connected but not locally connected space (like the Warsaw circle, or other examples) is a counterexample.